# C++ variable not recognized

Tags: c++, class, variables

I'am having a problem with a program I write. How you will see I'm calling a class I wrote in another file which is in the same folder when I try to use a variable I only get the error message: "C4700 The uninitialized local variable "query1" was used". I tried to name the variable diffrently but it didn't work.  Here's some code:

```
Save_status query1; // calling the class
if (query1.storage == true) // error is here, var "storage" is in class file 
{
    cout << "Choose your class:" << endl;
    cout << "human" << endl;
    cout << "magician" << endl;
    cout << "Centaurs" << endl;
    string choice;
    cin >> choice;
    class_wahl Wahl1;
    choice1.set_class (choice);
    fstream f;
    f.open ("Classwahl.txt", ios :: out);
    f << choice;
}
else if (query1.storage == false) // here it works!
{
    fstream f;
    f.open ("Classwahl.txt", ios :: in);
    string class;
    getline (f, class);
    cout << "class loaded. You play with the class" << class;
    class_wahl Wahl1;
    choice1.set_class (class);
}
```

I hope it's enough code. Already Thanks for the help!

Comment: You mean like #include "WhatEvar.h"?

Comment: The error message doesn't say that any variable is unrecognized, it says that you use the variable `query1` when it's *uninitialized*. Uninitialized variables and structures and arrays etc., will have an *indeterminate* value, and using that value will lead to *undefined behavior*. What *is* `Save_State`? How should `query1` be initialized? Please try to create a [mcve] to show us, one that contains enough information to see all structures and such, but also doesn't contain any unrelated errors (which your shown code have).

Comment: Please include the error verbatim. Does it complain about `query1` or about `query1.storage`?

Comment: Also please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that class `Save_status` lacks a constructor. Check your C++ book on how to write one.

Comment: The `Save_status` structure could have a constructor, but it just doesn't initialize its members (or at least not the `storage` member).